# Chart axis labels — Use $1M (million) short form instead of full $1,000,000 number

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016, currency-format

I have a PivotChart in Excel 2016 that has dollar amounts as the x-axis.

[image]

Currently, the labels are formatted as full numbers. Example: `$1,000,000`.

Is there a way to format the labels by replacing the zeros with an "M" for millions? Example: `$1M`.

---

*For bonus points, is there proper terminology to describe this technique? If so, feel free to suggest a better title. It'd be good to use a title that people can find when googling this issue.*

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom numbering format in the Format Axis options: `$#,##0,,"M"`.

[image]

[image]

---

Source:

LinkedIn Learning (Paid) - Excel PivotTables: Mastering PivotTables and PivotCharts - [Designing Interactive Dashboards video](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/excel-pivottables-mastering-pivottables-and-pivotcharts/designing-interactive-dashboards?autoplay=true&u=107513498) (7:52)